# Standardizing a binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Let $Y$ be a binomial random variable with parameters $n = 72$ and $p = 1/3$.

a) Find the exact probability $P(22 ≤ Y ≤ 28)$.

b) Is the condition $n ≥ 9 \left( \frac{\max(p, 1−p)}{\min(p, 1−p)} \right)$ required to approximate the distribution of Y by a normal distribution (textbook p.380) satisfied? If yes, approximate
$P(22 ≤ Y ≤ 28)$ with a normal probability.

I found a. I got $0.6$ but when I apply the central limit theorem and standardize it, I get $8.485$ and $-4.2$.

This already looks really wrong but I put it in R anyways by doing `pnorm(8.485) - pnorm(-4.2)` and I get $.999$.

The weird thing is if i code

`pnorm(28,24,4)-pnorm(22,24,4)`  I get $.53$.
Then I remembered the .5 rule so I did `pnorm(28.5,24,4)-pnorm(21.5,24,4)`  which is $.65$ and doing `pnorm(28,24,4)-pnorm(21,24,4)` gave me $.61$ which is REALLY close now to the answer. So I'm pretty sure the normal distribution DOES work in this case but I do not know why everytime I standardize it I get a big mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$np=24$$

$$npq=16$$

CLT in the version of [De Moivre- Laplace](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem) is

$$\frac{\Sigma_i X_i-np}{\sqrt{npq}}\sim \Phi$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{P}[22\leq Y\leq 28]=\mathbb{P}[21.5<Z<28.5]= $$

$$=\Phi\left[\frac{28.5-24}{4}\right]- \Phi\left[\frac{21.5-24}{4}\right] = 0.87-0.27=0.6 $$

Comment: isnt the denominator not 4?
Its SD / Sqrt(n)
SD = 4 and Sqrt(n)= Sqrt(72)
So isnt it actually
Sqrt(72)*(28.5-24) / 4  ? and similarly for the other half

Comment: That is the formula is this right so how is your denominator just 4?
$\frac{\bar{Y} - mean}{ SD / \sqrt{n} }$

Comment: @RandomGuy57: Need to test $$n \geq 9\bigg(\frac{\max(p,1-p)}{\min(p,1-p)}\bigg)$$ first prior to approximating the distribution of $Y$ by a normal distribution, as you had indicated in your question.

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris yeah and it holds up

Comment: @RandomGuy57 : I am very slowly in answering, I am writing with a cell phone but I added some details, hope it helps

Comment: helped a lot thank you